# Android In APP billing not firing event in my class

Tags: android, event-handling, in-app-purchase

I am using the 'Dungeon' example as a basis for my code, so it is the standard examplecode for now.

I can call the Market place and successfully place an order. Within BillingReciever the event
public void onReceive is called twice, as I would expect and I can put a breakpoint there and see the result which is fine.

checkResponseCode gets called too and starts

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Consts.ACTION_RESPONSE_CODE);
    intent.setClass(context, BillingService.class);
    intent.putExtra(Consts.INAPP_REQUEST_ID, requestId);
    intent.putExtra(Consts.INAPP_RESPONSE_CODE, responseCodeIndex);
    context.startService(intent);
```

And there the execution stops, and my app returns to a run state.

I have an extended PurchaseObserver class which is supposed to respond to billing changes, which  I have tried starting two different ways

```
mPurchaseObserver = new iPurchaseObserver(this,mHandler);

private class iPurchaseObserver extends PurchaseObserver {
            public iPurchaseObserver(UpgradeActivity upgradeActivity, Handler handler) {
                super(upgradeActivity, handler);
            }
```

And

```
mPurchaseObserver = new iPurchaseObserver(mHandler);

private class iPurchaseObserver extends PurchaseObserver {
            public iPurchaseObserver( Handler handler) {
                super(upgradeActivity.this, handler);
            }
```

None of the events/methods within the PurchaseObserver are fired, i.e onPurchaseStateChange.

I am suspecting it is the Activity Context I am passing or using when constructing my PurchaseObserver, but I am not sure, and advise would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found it, after loads and loads of wasted time. I had put the classes in a folder, when I moved them back to the root, they worked.

Comment: Can you please explain this further, I am dealing with same issue and reaching nowhere.